Как запустить C# программу на android в termux?
Есть у меня программа телеграм бот на C# как можно ее запустить на телефоне в termux?

может тут есть ответ? https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/ixktu0/does_anyone_know_how_to_install_telegramcli_on/
